# php_apcu.dll extension for symfony2.8 recommend php accelerator on xampp

Tags: php, symfony, accelerator

On windows 7 xampp 5.6.19 and symfony 2.8 dev environment configuration i was prompted "install and/or enable a php accelerator (highly recommended)". How to resolve this recommendation/warning?

Answer (score 18):

I found the answer to my question here: http://www.ivangabriele.com/php-how-to-install-php-accelerator-in-xampp/

here is instruction just in case the site goes away:

1. to show you PHP configuration via the PHP function phpinfo()
2. to get 2 precious informations :

   - architecture: x86 or x64?
   - TS (Thread Safe) or NTS (Non Thread Safe)?
3. to download the corresponding DLL (including your PHP version):
   http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu/4.0.8/windows
   (PHP 7: https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu/5.1.17/windows)
4. to copy/paste the DLL file within your extensions directory (C:\xampp\php\ext)
5. to edit your `php.ini` file (i.e. within `C:/xampp/php` directory)
6. to add this line inside Dynamic Extensions part :

   ```
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Dynamic Extensions ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

   [...]

   extension=php_apcu.dll
   ```
7. finally, to restart Apache - done.

NOTE: It is php_apcu.dll not php_apc.dll and click on Windows icon for Windows versions https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu

Tested and works on Windows 10.

Comment: apc.enabled=1 apc.shm_size=32M apc.ttl=7200 apc.enable_cli=1 apc.serializer=php

Comment: Ends up with error "php_apcu.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.\r\n in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: In step 6, Please add the dynamic extension like below.


extension=apcu

           Hopefully it will work fine :)

Comment: For those that get error " %1 is not a valid Win32 application.", first check your php version with `php -v` and download a DLL that matches your version, e.g. mine says 7.2 & I have downloaded http://pecl.php.net/package/APCu/5.1.12/windows . If you have XAMPP try the x86 version download